# Using JQuery replaceWith with a JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my html:

```
<div class="timer">Not Started</div>
```

And JS/JQ:

```
var seconds = 10;
  var minutes = 0;

  setTimeout("updateTimer()", 1000);

  function updateTimer() {

     if (seconds == 0 && minutes != 0) {
        minutes -= minutes;
        seconds = 59;
        alert (seconds);
     } else if (seconds == 1 && minutes == 0) {
        alert ('done');
     } else {
        seconds = seconds - 1;
        //alert (seconds);
        $(".timer").replaceWith(seconds);

     }

     setTimeout("updateTimer()", 1000);

  }
```

Instead of replacing Not Started with 10, 9, 8..., Not Started disappears.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, install FireBug add-on, after that easiest to find this kind of errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".timer").text(seconds);
```

You can't replace a DOM node with a string.

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/eFrst/2).

You could simplify your logic further by making use of `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, and use total seconds for easier calculations and remove minutes.

```
var seconds = 10, minutes = 0;
var totalSeconds = (minutes * 60) + seconds;

var timerId = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);

function updateTimer() {
    $('.timer').text(totalSeconds % 60);

    if (totalSeconds == 0) {
        alert("done");
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }

    totalSeconds--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replaceWith will replace the entire div, not just the contents. Try this instead:

```
$(".timer").html(seconds);
```